# Home page Component

Tags: home-page-component, customer-community, partner-communities

I have a query that can we add Videos In the Home page component ?
In my web app i want to to add a video tutorial whenever a user registered in a community he can see a video tutorial in the home page component  and follow the steps by watching the videos.

Comment: i also want this.. Its interesting to know whether we can add or not

Answer (score 0):

You can try HTML5 video tag. Create a visualforce page with this tag. Then create a home page component as a Visualforce Area. And add that to the home page layout.

```
<apex:page>
<html> 
<body> 

<video width="400">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" Controls="true" />
</video>

</body> 
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Since the visualforce area will be jailed in a security silo in form of an iframe, the user experience may be poor using a 400px video inside a 200px sidebar.

Comment: @Shailesh Patil the thing is that the development mode  is open  in the home page component. Registered users  can see the code. how to remove this ?